# not possible to install lubuntu in vmware player?

Tags: lubuntu, windows-10, vmware-player

I just replaced my ssd on my pc. I installed VMWare and have the lubuntu 20.04 iso. When I create a new virtual machine I only get the possibility to run the lubuntu image from the virtual drive, I can't install it...

Before reinstalling Windows 10 on my new drive, I had lubuntu installed as a VM with no problems.

Am I doing something wrong?

Windows 10, VMware 16.1, lubuntu 20.04

HELP!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your issue isn't with your host and virtualization software? Sounds like it to me.  The only issue with Lubuntu I can see is you didn't verify the ISO https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug with lubuntu 20.
Without a notice, lubuntu 20 removed the installer from boot manager and moved it inside the live version.
You need to boot live version, then install lubuntu by clicking on the Install lubuntu icon on the desktop.
It's the standard way now, this "problem" has nothing to do with a VM.

I wish authors did mention this change in boot manager / GRUB.
There is not much information on web about the change at this time e.g. if you search "no install option".
I wasted a lot of time on this, as I also assumed something's wrong with the VM.

I say it's a bug, as by definition a software bug is when something is not behaving as expected.
It might be by an error, or a lack of oversight.
It's expected you can run live OS or install it in the boot manager. But the options to install is now missing in boot loader without an explanation.

Yes, the manual describes the install process correctly:
https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html

Did someone expected a user will read the manual after years and hundreds of previous installations?

[image: boot manager]
[image: install icon on the desktop]